# ACF phone number field make click to call

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have a multi vendor website where vendors place their product with phone number. So, phone number is variable.
I did "Phone Number" field it with ACF Pro.
Now I'm trying to make ACF phone number field "Click to Call"

I used this code but didn't help:

```
function convert_phone_to_link ($value, $post_id, $field) {
  if (!$value) {
    // no value
    return $value;
  }
  // get the tel link field
  $tel_link = get_field('tel_link_field');
  if (!$tel_link) {
    // no link
    return $value;
  }
  $value = '<a href="tel:'.$tel_link.'">'.$value.'</a>';
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: What does "didn't help" mean? What were you hoping the output would be, and what was it instead?

Comment: When I applied this code, nothing has happened. Had no effect.